# custom font for CircleProgress Bar Android

Tags: android, fonts, android-progressbar

I'm using this library from github to get CircleProgress. All is working fine, but I would like to use a custom font for the porcentage.

attrs for ArchProgress

```
<declare-styleable name="ArcProgress">
    <attr name="arc_progress" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="arc_angle" format="float"/>
    <attr name="arc_stroke_width" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_max" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="arc_unfinished_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="arc_finished_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="arc_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_text_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="arc_suffix_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="arc_suffix_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_suffix_text_padding" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_bottom_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="arc_bottom_text_size" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Any one knows how to add a custom font to text in this progress bar(ArcProgress) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to download the code and edit the code as they explain [here](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/issues/73)